# How can i unit test my repository and viewmodel?

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, mvvm, mockito

I want to unit test my viewmodel and repository but I don't know how I can achieve that. I have made a start wit the viewmodeltestclass but I don't know how I can go further and what the best approach is. Should I also test my endpoint class and mainactivity? can someone help me please?

This is my endpoint class:

```
interface VenuesEndpoint {

    @GET("v2/venues/search")
    suspend fun get(
        @Query("near") city: String,
        @Query("limit") limit: String = Constants.LIMIT,
        @Query("radius") radius: String = Constants.RADIUS,
        @Query("client_id") id: String = Constants.CLIENT_ID,
        @Query("client_secret") secret: String = Constants.CLIENT_SECRET,
        @Query("v") date: String
    ): VenuesMainResponse

}
```

My repository class:

```
 private val _data: MutableLiveData<VenuesMainResponse?> = MutableLiveData(null)
    val data: LiveData<VenuesMainResponse?> get() = _data

    suspend fun fetch(city: String, date: String) {

        val retrofit = ApiClient()
        val api = retrofit.retro.create(VenuesEndpoint::class.java)

        try {
            val response = api.get(
                city = city,
                date = date
            )
            _data.value = response
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.message.toString())
            _data.value = null
        }
    }

}
```

My viewmodel class:

```
class VenueViewModel() : ViewModel() {

    private val repository = VenuesRepository()
    val data: LiveData<VenuesMainResponse?> = repository.data
    fun getData(city: String, date: String) {

        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.fetch(city, date)
        }
    }

}
```

My mainActivity class:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val viewModel by viewModels<VenueViewModel>()
    private lateinit var adapter: HomeAdapter
    private var searchData: List<Venue>? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.main_search)

        viewModel.getData(
            city = Constants.CITY,
            date = Constants.DATE
        )

        viewModel.data
            .observe(this, Observer {

                it.let {
                    initAdapter()
                    rv_home.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    if (it != null) {
                        adapter.setData(it.response.venues.sortedBy { myObject -> myObject.name })
                        searchData = it.response.venues.sortedBy { myObject -> myObject.name }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, Constants.ERROR_MESSAGE_API, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
            })
}
```

My ViewModelTest class:

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class VenueViewModelTest : TestCase() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: VenueViewModel

    @Before
    public override fun setUp() {
        super.setUp()
        viewModel = VenueViewModel()
    }


    @Test
    fun testVenueViewModel()
    {
       
    }


}
```